# Get if a drag and drop was done from the asset browser in python?

Tags: python, asset-browser

My idea is to use a modal operator, or a modal function that runs in the background.

The idea is to get an if statemen event based on a hypothetical drag and drop from the asset browser.

```
def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'TIMER':
        # Dummy Example:

        # if drag_and_drop_event:
        #     print("Drag and drop event from asset browser")

    return {'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

I don't know if that's the correct approach. I can't find a better idea than this.

So I limit myself to this question, precisely, capture any drag and drop event from the asset browser.

As @Gorgius suggested in the comments, better to use a `bpy.app.timer` for this example and not a modal

```
def in_1_seconds():
    # Dummy Example:

    # if drag_and_drop_event:
    #     print("Drag and drop event from asset browser")
    return 1.0

bpy.app.timers.register(in_1_seconds, first_interval=1)
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to get this event with the python API (yet). Also be careful with modal operators running in the background, they deactivate autosave. Better use application timers for that

Comment: Yeah, I made an example with a modal, but it was better to do it with bpy.app.timers with a function

Comment: I do not think there is any option or code to do that. Only way that I can think of, to get past this, is by using application timers. For more information on them, use this link: [Application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html)

Comment: I am not sure but if you drag and drop in python it might create lag. It allows you to get round it by using drag and drop on the actual website by loading it and then dragging it straight onto the picture.

Comment: @Z-animator Yes exactly, it was one of the plausible ways. But I really don't know what API to use to intercept a drag and drop. (I added it in the question in addition to the modal)